# Msg 232, Level 16, State 3, Line 5 Arithmetic overflow error for type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, msbi

how can i find the difference between two variables?

```
error is Msg 232, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = -39827814763.955299.

Msg 232, Level 16, State 3, Line 12
Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = -39827814763.950142.
```

query is below..
TIA

```
declare  @sql int 
declare @sql1 int
declare @sql3 int

set @sql = (select sum(sfg.amount) as VM_Amount_LCY
  from Setup_Company sc inner join stg_dim_dimension02 sdd on 
sdd.company_id = sc.company_id inner  join stg_fact_dimension_set_entry fdse on fdse.dim02_sk = sdd.dimension_id and fdse.company_id=sdd.company_id
inner join stg_fact_gl sfg on sfg.[dimension set id] = fdse.[Dimension Set ID] and sfg.company_id= fdse.company_id )



set @sql1 = (select sum(sfg.amount) as BI_Amount_LCY from [NORRIQ Drink-IT BI 2013 India].dbo.Setup_Company sc inner join [NORRIQ Drink-IT BI 2013 India].dbo.dim_dimension02 sdd on 
sdd.company_id = sc.company_id inner  join [NORRIQ Drink-IT BI 2013 India].dbo.fact_dimension_set_entry fdse on fdse.dim02_sk = sdd.dimension_id and fdse.company_id=sdd.company_id
inner join [NORRIQ Drink-IT BI 2013 India].dbo.fact_gl sfg on sfg.[dimension set id] = fdse.[Dimension Set ID] 
and sfg.company_id= fdse.company_id )


select @sql3 = (-(@sql) - (-(@sql1)))
```

Comment: Seems like int is too small. Use largest decimal (or bigint if you need large integer) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
-39827814763.955299
```

The above value is decimal and you are trying to store it an INT.INT can store numbers in below range..

```
-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
```

You can use BIGINT to overcome Ari thematic overflow..

```
declare  @sql BIGINT 
declare @sql1 BIGINT 
declare @sql3 BIGINT
```

But with above datatypes you are losing precision,if you want precision,use numeric like below..

```
 declare  @sql numeric(22,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Type of expression in SUM determines return type in your case sfg.amount. You can CAST for example to BIGINT before you perform the SUM like follows:

```
SELECT SUM( CAST( sfg.amount AS BIGINT )) ....
```